# How do I find the maximum and minimum points of f(x,y) on a unit circle?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I'm supposed to find the maximum and minimum values of $f(x,y) = xy^2$ on the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

My work so far:

$\bigtriangledown f = (y^2 ,xy)$

Let $g(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 $
$\bigtriangledown g = (2x,2y)$

$\bigtriangledown f = \lambda \bigtriangledown g$

and I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: See the second example: http://www.ccs.tulane.edu/~chiayu/CalculusIII2009/Lec19.pdf (page 3), for how you can do this using LM's.

Comment: $f(x,y)=xy^2=x(1-x^2)=x-x^3=g(x)$ and $g'(x)=1-3x^2=0\implies x=\pm 1/\sqrt 3$.  The maximum (minimum) occurs at $x=1/\sqrt 3$ ($-1/\sqrt 3$) and have values $\pm \sqrt 3/9$.

Comment: @Dr.MV: values $\pm\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}=\pm\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{9}$ but I agree that is the most efficient approach.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes; I did the evaluation in my head ... bad idea. ;-))

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the old-school approach? Every point $(x,y)$ on the unit circle can be written as $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ for some $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$, and the stationary points of $\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)^2$ lie at the roots of $\sin(\theta)\left(2\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta\right)$, hence the maximum is attained at $\theta=\arctan\sqrt{2}$ and its value is $\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{9}$. By symmetry ($(x,y)\mapsto(-x,y)$) the minimum is just the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just solve $\bigtriangledown f = \lambda \bigtriangledown g$ to find a couple of triplets $(x,y,\lambda)$. Then compare values of $f$ over those points.

$\bigtriangledown f = \lambda \bigtriangledown g$ gives two equations, and $g=0$ gives a third one. So, it is solvable.